# SharePoint list to replace Google Sheet

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

In my organisation we have this Google Sheet that is like a calendar for publishing dates for social media. Nothing else is done in Google so I want to replace it. Thing is I don't know where to start.

This sheet holds information about:

- Dates and week (like a calendar)
- Where to update
- Who is updating at a certain date
- and some standard update shifts
  (simplified picture)

I want to know: is it possible to create for example a SharePoint list with power automate that updates monthly with dates, weeks, campaigns and standard shifts and the somebody can add rest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a SharePoint list, you can copy the Google Sheets to an Excel file. Then upload this Excel file to SharePoint.

Then share the link to the new Excel file with your team members. They will be able to view and modify this file simultaneously, similar to Google Sheets.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried out but backlash was..interesting. Many people was infuriated that they have to use Excel now (don't know why the google sheet is okay). That's why I try to think something else.

Comment: You might like to let them know they can use the online version of excel in a web browser tab, by starting in SharePoint. If this is people working on social media posts, then they probably want it open in their browser. Also TBH Marketing people just use Google everything :\

Comment: Oh they know the browser version. It's the fact that they have to "learn" excel now. Yes I know it's similar to google sheet but any changes that involves new software or similar causes "we don't have time for this"-snowball effect.